# laravel 4 Cannot Retrieve ALL results ? pivot table Many to Many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, pivot

I am a bit stuck on this...
I have 3 tables: photographers, languages and languages_spoken (intermediate table).

I am trying to retrieve all the languages spoken by a photographer. I defined my models like this:

```
class Photographer extends Eloquent {
/**
 * Defining the many to many relationship with language spoken
 * 
 */
public function languages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language', 'languages_spoken', 'language_id', 'photographer_id');
}
class Language extends Eloquent {
/**
 * Defining the many to many relationship with language spoken
 * 
 */
public function photographers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Photographer', 'languages_spoken', 'language_id', 'photographer_id')
        ->withPivot('speakslanguages');
}
```

This is how I was trying to retrieve all the results for the logged in photographer:

```
 $photographer   = Photographer::where('user_id', '=', $user->id);

            if ($photographer->count()) {
                $photographer       = $photographer->first();

                // TEST

                $spokenlang         = $photographer->languages;
                die($spokenlang);

                // END TEST

            } else {
                return App::abort(404);
            }
```

The problem is that in my db I have 4 entries for the same photographer. but when I do this I only get the last result...

**[{"id":"3","language_name":"Afrikaans","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","native_name":"Afrikaans","ISO639_1":"af","pivot":{"language_id":"3","photographer_id":"3"}}]**

Any idea on what is wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to belongsToMany should be the *foreign* key.

In the Photographer class:

```
public function languages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language', 'languages_spoken', 'language_id', 'photographer_id');
}
```

...should be:

```
public function languages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language', 'languages_spoken', 'photographer_id');
}
```

In the Language class:

```
public function photographers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Photographer', 'languages_spoken', 'language_id', 'photographer_id')
    ->withPivot('speakslanguages');
}
```

Should be:

```
public function photographers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Photographer', 'languages_spoken', 'language_id')
    ->withPivot('column1', 'column2', 'column3'); // withPivot() takes a list of columns from the pivot table, in this case languages_spoken
}
```

But, since you're not even using strange keys, you don't need to pass that third parameter at all.

So this is just fine:

```
public function languages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language', 'languages_spoken');
}
```

And:

```
public function photographers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Photographer', 'languages_spoken')
    ->withPivot('column1', 'column2', 'column3'); // withPivot() takes a list of columns from the pivot table, in this case languages_spoken
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works! now quick question, I don't see the need for the pivot table... when do I need to call it in a model? I thought my language_spoken table was already acting as an intermediate table... this pivot table is a bit confusing to me...

Comment: @commander You only need to use withPivot() when you have columns other than the keys on the pivot table.  For instance, if there is a `proficiency` column *in addition to* the key columns and you have like `fluent` / `barely speaks` / etc. as values to show how proficient each photographer is in each language, then you could call `->withPivot('proficiency')` in the relationship, and then `$photographer->pivot->proficiency` for instance.